# Eclipse: Double semi-colon on an import

Tags: java, eclipse, import, syntax-error

Using Eclipse, if I have an extra semicolon on an import line (not the last import line), I see a syntax error in the IDE. However, this compiles fine outside of the IDE (Maven in this case).

Example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;; //notice extra semicolon
import java.util.List;
```

Does anyone else see this behavior? Why is this showing as a syntax error? I am working with someone who keeps pushing these this to source control and it is irritating me (they clearly aren't using Eclipse).

Full disclosure... I am using SpringSource Tool Suite 2.8.0.

Comment: quick note on those classes to fix them quickly use the keyboard shortcut ctrl+shift+o this will fix all the imports of the currently opened java file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a syntax error because an `import` is a declaration, not a statement; you can't have statements outside of a class.

See [JLS 7.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#70209) for details, but essentially, import declarations end with a single `;`.

For example, single-type import:

```
SingleTypeImportDeclaration:
   import TypeName ;
```

In the JLS's description of the grammar, there's no ambiguity that would allow an empty import statement, and except for packages, nothing else can go in a compilation unit's premable.

```
CompilationUnit:
        [[Annotations] package QualifiedIdentifier   ;  ] {ImportDeclaration}
{TypeDeclaration}

ImportDeclaration:
     import [ static] Identifier {   .   Identifier } [   .     *   ] ;
```

I take this to mean that Eclipse is correct, JDK compiler incorrect.

Comment: So, you are telling me JDK bug and not a single upvote? Sheesh

Comment: @smp7d *I'm* saying that, but that's a loooong shot from it being correct. Whether or not it's a bug; meh. FWIW, [this](http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6963934) is slightly related. What platform are you on?

Comment: java version "1.6.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode), Windows 7 Pro SP1

Comment: This was recognized as a JDK bug: javac should not accept a simicolon in that location, and Eclipse is right to reject it. See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8027682

Answer (score 1):

It's not a compiler error, although there are times where it might be a sign of a bug (some code that was accidentally deleted, etc.)

You probably have your Eclipse warnings set quite strict. I like mine like that. Your best approach is to set up some coding standards and enforce them with something like Checkstyle and/or Findbugs. At least one of those will find that and slap your colleagues wrist!

*EDIT*

It seems Eclipse (at least 3.6, I didn't test 3.7) does indeed report a double semi-colon after an import statement as a compile error, regardless of your "empty statement" settings. Eclipse has its own built-in compiler, separate from the JDK compiler. So if Eclipse is not liking this, but the JDK compiler is, it suggests one or other of them has a bug (or at least a different interpretation of the JLS!).

I would suggest raising this as a bug against Eclipse - purely because they tend to be very responsive in investigating things and explaining why they think they're right and raising/chasing bug reports with the JDK developers.

Comment: Eclipse reports it as a compilation error as far as I can tell. It says: Syntax error on token ";"

Comment: verified. if I try to run I get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem"

Comment: As I said, you've probably got empty statements set to error, at a guess. The exception you're reporting doesn't add any more information. Eclipse can attempt to run code that doesn't compile - e.g. you can run unit tests on a class even if an unrelated class doesn't compile. All that exception tells you is that you're trying to run code that has a "compile error" in it. But, as I said, I suspect the "compile error" is being invented by Eclipse because it's set to be too strict - stricter than the JLS.

Comment: "Empty statement" is set to ignore. As I said, this is is fine on the last import line. Is also fine on any other code. In Java-> Compiler->Errors/Warnings nothing is set to "Error".

Comment: Eclipse is right to signal an error. The JDK is incorrect to accept it: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8027682

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse as an IDE has the feature/option to identify potential code deletes and thus marks that as an error.

I think this can be set under java -> compiler -> preferences. Please see this link.

http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/compiler/ref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm

But I have not tried it.

Comment: I am aware. My question is as to why Eclipse chokes on this.

Comment: Updated my answer, I missed the eclipse part first.

Answer (score 1):

You will no longer see this with [Eclipse 4.15 (2020.03)](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.15/jdt.php#import-completion):

> ### No more spurious semicolon from import completion
>
> Almost 18 years ago, it was reported that completion for imports adds an unnecessary semicolon if one already exists (like when changing an existing import).
>
> **Now this extra semicolon is no longer inserted.**